# Can't put data to the top by appendChild

Tags: javascript

I have an AJAX XMLHttpRequest grid. I output it by innerHTML. I have a refresh function which triggers every 60 seconds retrieving fresh data. The problem is I use innerHTML += , which doesn't work the way I want it, it adds the fresh data to the bottom. And i want it to put it to the top.

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: What kind of content do you receive? You could use `.insertBefore()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.insertBefore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var element = document.getElementById("content"),
    newContent, // ajax stuff here
    currentText = element.innerHTML;
element.innerHTML = newContent + currentText;
```

Essentially, we're getting the current text and putting the new content before it.